# K&R C programming language book. Section 1.4 about Symbolic Constants. Why to use them?

Tags: c, constants

The authors support the use of symbolic constants with #define and a name in capitals. What's the point since we can do the say with assigning a variable with a constant value, i.e. int step = 20

I'm a begginer in C...

Comment: you'll find there's often more than one way to do things, and there are also best/historical practices. What is the "best" way depends on the context, and can be up for debate anyway. `#define` macros have long been used in C for constants. They're nothing more than preprocessor text substitutions. It's quite possible `int step = 20` will serve your needs too, but that's a modifiable variable (bad for constants) and may have scoping issues depending on where it's defined. Without more context I don't think there's much left to say.

Comment: You're reading a 46 year old book. Suggest you upgrade to some newer material.

Comment: Logic in the preprocessor is often used for decisions about which code to pass to the compiler at all -- think "if we're on Linux, we need to include _this_ header, but if we're on MacOS we need _that_ header". You _can't do that at all_ with a regular variable. Same for the close cousin "if our glibc version is newer than this number, then we want to use this code...", so integer comparisons come up in practice in the preprocessor in real/practical modern-day situations.

Answer (score 1):

At the time C was developed, compilers had little or no ability to remember the values of variables, and it was early in the development of the semantics of programs. The major purpose of a declaration `int step = 20;` was to cause memory to be reserved for `step`, to remember its type was `int`, and to generate instructions or other object-module code that initialized the memory to 20.

Remembering “values” of macro names was managed in a separate part of the compilation process, called a preprocessor, whose job was to process the directives beginning with `#`.

The original idea was that `int step = 20;` would cause `step` to be set to 20 when the program started running. Knowing it was 20 when the program was being compiled was not part of the initial plan.

There are places in C where the compiler needs to know a value at the time it is compiling. For example, when an array is defined outside a function, as with `int x[328];`, the compiler needs to know how much space to reserve for the array. It must have a “constant” value for that, not a “variable” like `step`. The compiler would not know what to do with `int x[step];`. The preprocessor took care of this; it processed the `#define` directives and replaced occurrences of the macro `step` with the replacement token `20`. Then the compiler would see `int x[20];`, not `int x[step];`, and that would work.

Compilers have developed a great deal over the years, and today a preprocessor may be integrated into the compiler. Additionally, code has been written for some compilers that will remember the values of variables that are defined as constant (with `const`) and allow their use in some places where constants are needed. However, this has not yet been made a part of the C standard, and not all compilers support it. (C++ is further along in this.)

Also consider this:

```
int step = 20;

int x[step];

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    int y[step];
    … // More code.
}
```

At `int x[step];`, we can figure `step` has the value 20, taking the initialization to occur as soon as we compile `int step = 20;` instead of when the program starts running. But what is the value of `step` at `int y[step];`? The value could have changed in the call to `foo`, since the code in `foo` might assign a new value to `step`. (Modern C allows defining arrays with values computed at run-time but does not currently require compilers to support that.) So there are various problems attempting to use variables for values the compiler needs to know when it is compiling.

Answer (score 0):

> The authors support the use of symbolic constants with #define and a name in capitals. What's the point since we can do the say with assigning a variable with a constant value, i.e. int step = 20

- Variables, even if declared with the `const` qualifier, are not on the language spec's list of expressions that are or can appear in "constant expressions".  Constant expressions are required for the dimensions of (ordinary) arrays and in initializers of variables with static storage duration, among other places.  Macros that expand to constants or constant expressions can be used in these places.
- Variables occupy storage, whereas macro-defined constants effectively do not.  That is, variables impose a memory usage cost.
- Variables' values need to be read from storage to be used (to a first approximation), whereas macro constants generally do not.  That is, variables impose a performance cost.
- Variables declared in header files either are static, or are subject to the one-definition rule.  The former tends to increase the required storage and sometimes draws useless compiler diagnostics.  The latter makes code more complicated and makes the value of the variable more difficult to discover at development time.  None of that applies to macros.